# clisp, CLOS: retyping an object, later

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clos

Suppose I have a class `animal`, with subclasses `horse`, `duck`, and `rabbit`.  Suppose I use `make-instance` to make several objects of class `animal`.  Much later, I discover, for each of these objects, that it's actually a `horse`, or a `duck`, or a `rabbit`.  Is there a way to retype these objects?  Simply creating new objects of the appropriate subtypes and copying over the data in all the slots, would be clumsy, because by this time such an object is already represented in lists which are in slots of yet other objects, and I'd have to go through those lists and replace the old objects with the new ones.

Keep the same old objects and subclassify them.  Can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CHANGE-CLASS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_chg_cl.htm#change-class), a standard Common Lisp function.

Comment: ... and I don't know how I missed this.  It was right there in CLtL.  Thank you!

Comment: Oh come on now. You're obviously posting a question you already know the answer to in order to evangelize Lisp. :)